# Why am I getting this error? org.bukkit.event.EventException: null

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I try to code that if I right click on a Sign I will teleport to a position. It is working BUT in the Console I get an Error and idk why. This is my code:

```
public class schildJNR implements Listener {

@EventHandler
public void schildKlickEvent(PlayerInteractEvent event) {
    Player player = event.getPlayer();
    if(event.getPlayer() instanceof Player && event != null) {
        if (event.getClickedBlock().getType() == Material.SPRUCE_WALL_SIGN) {

            Sign sign = (Sign) event.getClickedBlock().getState();

            if (sign.getLine(0).equalsIgnoreCase("Die Schlucht")) {
                player.teleport(new Location(Bukkit.getWorld("world"), 295.14f, 69, 46.54f, -90.1f, 0.9f));
            } else if (sign.getLine(0).equalsIgnoreCase("Schatzsuche")) {
                player.teleport(new Location(Bukkit.getWorld("world"), 74.59f, 63, 237.51f, -91.4f, 1.3f));
            } else if (sign.getLine(0).equalsIgnoreCase("Fichtenwald")) {
                player.teleport(new Location(Bukkit.getWorld("world"), -5.43f, 78, 172.57f, 179.7f, 1.6f));
           }
        }
    } else {
        player.sendMessage("ERROR");
    }
}
```

The error is: org.bukkit.event.EventException: null [...] Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
What am I making wrong?

Comment: Please post the full error details, including the stack trace.

Answer (score 2):

Your order of expressions in the if is incorrect, you need to first check if it's null and then if it is instanceof player.

```
if(event != null && event.getPlayer() instanceof Player) {
```

Answer (score 0):

ok I fixed it. I tried to execute the 'getClickedBlock()' method but if I for example punch in the air the 'PlayerInteractEvent' will be execute and then the code is trying to execute this: 'if (event.getClickedBlock().getType() == Material.SPRUCE_WALL_SIGN) {' but I doesn't klicked a block so there will be an error. I added a if condition and now it is working.